# Is it possible to create a link from the chart that sends us to a symbol?

Tags: pine-script

I have a screener that displays symbol names on the chart and I would like to know if it is possible to click on a symbol name on the chart to access the chart for that symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The table is not interactive.

You can do that manually by adding the assets to your watchlist.